# python3 exec() not working as expected in function call

Tags: python-3.x, function-calls

code1.py

```
if(__name__=="__main__"):
    var = "first_name"
    inp = "hello"
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (var,inp))
    print(first_name)
```

code2.py

```
def func():
    var = "first_name"
    inp = "hello"
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (var,inp))
    print(first_name)

if(__name__=="__main__"):
    func()
```

given two are two different codes
code1.py works as expected. code2.py shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bad.py", line 8, in <module>
    func()
  File "bad.py", line 5, in func
    print(first_name)
NameError: name 'first_name' is not defined
```

Can someone please explain why is this happening ?